# Oracle create automatic connections after open()

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, connection-pooling

when I create a new connection with C#, I can see that there are more connections open, but 4 of them are automatic created. This is the following SQL query, which get called, in the 4 connections:

```
SELECT parameter, VALUE
  FROM sys.nls_database_parameters
 WHERE parameter IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET')
```

These only get executed when I open the connection.. any ideas how to prevent them to get called, or close them after they get executed?
Or is the best solution to set pooling to false?

Any ideas??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The multiple connections are probably caused by connection pooling. If you invoke multiple database commands using different connection objects at the same time more connections need to be created. Default minimum pool size is 1 and pool increasing size is 5. So when you have one connection and you need more at the same time more sessions to the database can be open.

The data from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS is fetched because the client needs to be aware of the NLS settings. If non-managed Oracle.DataAccess is used the command is fired from non-managed code.